Airflow takes a random python file as a DAG and breaks it
I have a pipeline forlder with this structure:
project forlder 1
  |--project forlder 2
     |-- DAGS
       |--dag1
       |--dag2
       |--utils
          |-- __init__.py
          |--python folder
             |-- __init__.py
             |-- python.py

python.py is not a DAG and I run it in terminal whenever I need. (to parameterize my queries)
I get this error as the Airflow takes this python file as a DAG.
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/project folder2/DAGs/utils/python folder/python.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/project folder2/DAGs/utils/python folder/python.py", line 10, in <module>
    sql_file = sys.argv[2]  
IndexError: list index out of range

*** the python.py takes three arguments to run in terminal and here is the lines that caused error:
dag_directory = sys.argv[1]  
sql_file = sys.argv[2]
sql_path = os.getcwd() + '\\project folder2\\DAGs\\' + dag_directory + '\\sql\\' + sql_file  
direction = sys.argv[3]

Do you have any ideas how can I fix it?

Add .airflowignore file. The dag parser is picking up the word dag in your file

Thank you! I created that file and my problem was solved!
